# Content-Length should be specified for iterable data of type class 'dict'

Tags: python, python-3.4

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22403871/content-length-should-be-specified-for-iterable-data-of-type-class-dict) , [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29850153/python-3-4-using-urlopen-to-get-web-content-via-proxy), but didn't helped me much, getting same error still any idea whats causing the issue in below code.

```
try:
    request = urllib.request.Request(url,data=payload,method='PUT',headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
```

Error got:-  Content-Length should be specified for iterable data of type class 'dict'

Python version: 3.4

I thought issue should be solved long back as reported in Python 3.2  [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue11082)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`urllib.request` does not support passing in unencoded dictionaries; if you are sending JSON data you need to *encode* that dictionary to JSON yourself:

```
import json

json_data = json.dumps(payload).encode('utf8')
request = urllib.request.Request(url, data=json_data, method='PUT',
                                 headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```

You may want to look at installing the [`requests` library](https://requests.readthedocs.io/); it supports encoding JSON for request bodies out-of-the-box by using the `json` keyword argument:

```
import requests

response = requests.put(url, json=payload)
```

Note that the `Content-Type` header is set for you automatically.